# Recyclerview con setVisibility GONE no elimina espacio de la fila

Tags: android

En un fragment tengo un listado (`RecyclerView`) que viene de un Content Provider (SQLite).
Quiero que la fila 2 no se muestre, por lo que dentro de `onBindViewHolder` del Adapter, 
configuro `setVisibility(View.GONE)` a la posición 1 (que es la fila num 2), y efectivamente
no lo muestra pero muestra el espacio que ocupaba esa fila, es como si hubiera configurado
`setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`:

```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    if(position ==1){  
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    String p = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PrimerContract.COLUMN_POSICION));
    String it = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PrimerContract.COLUMN_ITEM));
    String mId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PrimerContract._ID));

    holder.mText1.setText("card "+position+"\n"+" id  "+mId);
    holder.mText2.setText(p);
    holder.mText3.setText(it);
  }
```

Se ve así con `View.GONE` y con `View.INVISIBLE`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo se puede eliminar ese espacio?

El xml del item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/row"
android:visibility="gone"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView01"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="01"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="00"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView01"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView02"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Con este RecyclerView se puede modificar la tabla SQlite que tambien alimenta a un spinner, de esta forma:

```
    String selection = PrimerContract.COLUMN_GRUPO + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"items"};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(PrimerContract.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, PrimerContract._ID);                                                                                                      
    String[] fromColumns = {PrimerContract.COLUMN_ITEM};  // lo que va mostrar el spinner
    int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1};

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Se pueden agregar, editar o eliminar items
 excepto los item 1 (sqlite id 1, se puede editar pero no eliminar) 
y 2 (sqlite id2, no se debe editar ni eliminar). Por eso es que quiero que el id2, que en el RecyclerView es
el row 1, no se muestre, en el spinner si se mostrará.

Ese RecyclerView se carga con un cursor loader:

```
 @Override
   public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
     return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), PrimerContract.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, PrimerContract._ID);     
}
```

**Otra Solución:**

Lo que quiero es que no se muestre lo que esta en la base de datos sqlite la fila 2 (id 2) que en el Recyclerview queda en la fila 2 (position 1).
La solución que da @Andrespengineer queda perfecta: no muestra la fila 2 del Recyclerview y no queda espacio.
Otra solución es que muestre todas las filas del RecyclerView pero que ninguna de ellas muestre el id 2 del SQlite. Esto se logra modificando el `Cursor Loader` de esta forma:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
String[] projection = new String[]{PrimerContract.COLUMN_ITEM, PrimerContract.COLUMN_POSICION, PrimerContract.COLUMN_GRUPO, PrimerContract._ID};
String selection = PrimerContract._ID + " NOT IN (?)";    // de esta columna no quiero que muestre
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"2"};               // el id 2
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), PrimerContract.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, PrimerContract._ID);
```

Comment: Coloca el xml del item de tu recyclerview para poder ayudarte

Comment: @4D1C70 listo el xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema al hacer `setVisibility` a `Gone`, es que el marco del item ya fue dibujado, porque se llamo `onCreateViewHolder` y esta tomando un espacio en el `RecyclerView`. Lo que debes hacer es cambiarle los parametros de la vista y volver su altura a cero. Esto hará que desaparezca dicha vista. Pero como en el `onBindViewHolder` se reciclaran dichas vistas. Debes volverla a su estado original.

En la clase del holder debes hacer:

```
private final View itemView;
```

En tu constructor:

```
{
. . .
   this.itemView = itemView;
. . .
}
```

Crea los métodos:

```
public void hideView(){
    /*Tipo del layout padre*/.LayoutParams parameters = new /*Tipo del layout padre*/.LayoutParams(/*Width declarado en tu layout*/, 0);
    this.itemView.setLayoutParams(parameters);

}

public void resetView(){
    /*Tipo del layout padre*/.LayoutParams parameters = new /*Tipo del layout padre*/.LayoutParams(/*Width original definido en tu layout*/, /*Height original definido en tu layout*/);
    this.itemView.setLayoutParams(parameters);
}
```

**Nota:** tanto para el `Width` como para el `Height` en los parametros puedes asignar: `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` o  `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` según hayas definido en el `Layout` de tu Item, si no definiste un tamaño fijo. Mientras que con el tipo de Layout padre me refiero a:

- LinearLayout
- FrameLayout
- RelativeLayout

etc... El que tengas de padre en el `Layout` de los Items.

En el `onBindViewHolder` entonces haces lo siguiente:

```
if(/*condicion*/) 
    holder.hideView();
else
    holder.resetView();
```

---

### Importante

Si tienes alguna regla adicional referente al Layout definida, digase por ejemplo: `orientation`, `margin`, `gravity`, etc... Debes definirla en los LayoutParams de los `metodos creados` también. De lo contrario, se le asignara solo el tamaño de la vista, mas no dichas propiedades. LayoutParams tiene metodos que te ayudan a definir todas esas propiedades en código. Si quieres clonar las propiedades que ya tiene definidas y guardarla en una variable puedes definir un onLayoutChangeListener y removerlo al asignarlas. Asi solo tendrias que igualarla a dichas propiedades en el `resetView();`.

Comment: quedó perfecto. Gracias